# Get memory corruption when using realloc function

Tags: c, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int ind=0;

void rea(int* function)
{
    ind+=1;
    function = realloc(function,sizeof(int) * ind);
    function[ind-1] = 1;
}


int main(void) 
{
    int* fun = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int a =0;
    while(a<400)
    {
        int v = 0;

        rea(fun);
        puts("a");
        a+=1;
        ind+=1;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it gives me the error: double free or corruption Aborted (core dumped). I increment the ind every time and [ind-1] to assign the value so it shouldn't out of bound.

Comment: Function arguments are passed by value in C. This means that `rea` modifies a *copy of* the `fun` pointer from `main`, which then gets discarded as soon as `rea` returns. You can modify `rea` to either return the reallocated pointer (like `realloc` itself does), or pass an `int **` argument to it, instead.

Comment: bad calling to realloc `function = realloc(function,sizeof(int) * ind);`. what do you want to reallocate?

Comment: @I'm trying to realloc the `function`.

Comment: Short version: Due to pass-by-value semantics of C, `function = ...` means *nothing* to the caller (`main`) of `rea`. It retains the original pointer value of `fun` in `main`, and eventually that can/will be dangling.

Comment: see the Jean's answer below. Any change to function has no impact on fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is pass-by-value, means that any parameter passed at a function called is not passed by itself but its value is copied into another new variable of a compatible type. Thus when you call:

```
rea(fun)
```

the **value** of `fun` is used to initialize the `function` parameter. Any change to `function` has no impact on `fun`. As `realloc` may move the old memory chunk to a new place, if this happens then it is not reflected to `fun`. Alas when you call `rea(fun)` at a later time, you then pass a value that is no more usable, already freed by memory management system.

A change may be:

```
void rea(int** function) { // get the address of the pointer
    ind+=1;
    *function = realloc(*function,sizeof(int) * ind); // eventually modify the pointer at the given address
    (*function)[ind-1] = 1;
}

int main(void)  {
    int *fun = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int a = 0;
    while (a<400) {
        int v = 0;   
        rea(&fun); // pass address of the pointer
        puts("a");
        a+=1;
        ind+=1;
    }
}
```

-----EDIT-----

`realloc` manual says, emphasize is mine

> The `realloc()` function **tries to change the size** of the allocation
>   pointed
>        to by ptr to size, and returns ptr.  If there is **not enough room to
>        enlarge** the memory allocation pointed to by ptr, realloc() **creates a new
>        allocation**, **copies as much of the old data** pointed to by ptr as will fit
>        to the new allocation, **frees the old allocation**, and returns a pointer to
>        the allocated memory.

Comment: But why this error occur after some execution? shouldn't occur at the beginning of the execution?

Comment: @SadSalad It happens only if memory is moved, which is not always the case. You'll never know when `realloc` moves... print memory address (in `main` and `rea`) and you will see.